# Pyplot animate image example not working in JupyterLab

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-lab

I am trying this example:

https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/animation/dynamic_image.html

I downloaded the attached notebook and opened it in JupyterLab desktop.
But the animation doesn't work. Here is the result I get:

[image]

Any ideas as to why it doesn't work?

Comment: I vaguely recall that you need to capture the ani instance and display it with a `HTML` tag (`HTML(anim.to_html5_video())`. Also, checkout  [this questino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47138023/matplotlib-animation-in-jupyter-notebook-creates-additional-empty-plot)

Comment: You may need to install `ipympl` (https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-desktop/pull/329) but I am not sure of this one.

Comment: Animations don't work inline. You need to set `%matplotlib qt` for interactive plots

Comment: yes, please use an interactive backend.  `%matplotlib notebook`, `%matplotlib widget` or `%matplotlib qt` should all work.  You are using `%matplotlib inline`, which is the (simple) default in Jupyter.